# How to pass reference from onClick to open modal

Tags: reactjs, onclick, material-ui

I have cards in my app that display a modal when clicked. I'm using Material UI so they're called Dialogs. I have an object (id, name, description) containing all the data for each card. So far I have a loop set up that displays each card with the corresponding title and picture, based on my JSON data. I'm trying to figure out how to pass a reference from whatever card is clicked to the modal and display the description depending on the modal selected.

I'll omit the code I don't think is necessary

```
export default ({courses}) => {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleClickOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true); 
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};

return (
    <Grid container className={mainGrid}>
      {Object.keys(courses).map((index, key) => {
        return (
          <Grid item xs key={key}>
            <Card className={cardStyle}>
              <CardActionArea onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                <CardMedia image={require(`../Assets/${courses[index].name}.png`)} className={media}/>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom className={cardTitle} variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {courses[index].name}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>  
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        );
      })};

      {/* Modal Element - I need to pass a reference here somehow*/}

      <CourseDialog 
        open={open} 
        onClose={handleClose} 
        classes={classes} 
      />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

```
// This is the Modal function, in the same file as the above code. This is where I want to display the description when the modal is clicked.

const CourseDialog = (props) => {

  const { classes, onClose, ...other } = props;

  function handleClose() {
    onClose();
  };

  return ( <div></div>  )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by making another hook for storing the selected value.

`const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState(null);`

Then when you call onClick=handleClickOpen you can also send the selected id in the params.

`onClick={handleClickOpen(index)}`

Then handleClickOpen function and CourseDialog will become

```
const handleClickOpen = (id) => {
  setSelectedId(id);
  setOpen(true);
};

<CourseDialog 
  open={open} 
  onClose={handleClose} 
  classes={classes}
  data={courses[selectedId]}
/>
```

This will probably solve your problem. If you face any issues then I can get this into a fiddle and give some similar example code.

Comment: Works good! Just had to change the `onClick={handleClickOpen(index)}` to `onClick={() => handleclickOpen(index)}` is that ok?

Comment: Yeah, that is perfect.